# tomcat fails to deploy when deployed from manager app

Tags: tomcat, war, tomcat8.5, war-filedeployment

I'm trying to upload a war file, sized 100~mb to tomcat for deployment.
I changed the max size in the manager app web xml,but still..
when I try to deploy it I get the usual chrome error of:
This Site can't be reached.
The connection was reset....
and on the web link I see:
http://localhost:8080/manager/html/upload?org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=91AF4BF3BAC5284FA3D567B8D2EE3DEA

anyone has an idea why this might happen?

Comment: Same problem here, did you find a solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [After add maven dependency, org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF\_NONCE error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39772669/after-add-maven-dependency-org-apache-catalina-filters-csrf-nonce-error-message)